# How can I assign different symbols to different groups in a lattice plot?

Tags: r, lattice

Say I have 3 groups with 3 dots each on the plot and I need a black & white version where the 3 dots of the 3 groups are all displayed with different symbols.
How should I specify the panel.superpose function?

http://www.r-bloggers.com/working-with-themes-in-lattice-graphics/
http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/lattice/html/panel.superpose.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I tend to use the same general strategy laid out in the blog post you linked to.

Starting with `standard.theme()`, you can make tweaks to settings until you have a customized theme that best fits your own needs. Once you've got something you like, you can just plug it in via the `par.settings` argument whenever you want to use it.

```
library(lattice)
# Start work on your own black-and-white theme
myTheme <- standard.theme(col = FALSE)
myTheme$superpose.symbol$pch <-1:7

# These are the kinds of commands you can use to explore the list of available
# settings as well as their current settings.
names(myTheme)
myTheme$superpose.symbol

# Compare the results of your own theme to those produce by lattice's
# default settings.
library(gridExtra)
p1 <- xyplot(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length, group= Species, data = iris,
             main = "lattice's default theme")
p2 <- xyplot(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length, group= Species, data = iris,
             par.settings = myTheme,
             main = "My customized theme")
grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol=2)
```

[image]

Comment: perfect, educational, encyclopedic answer I learned more from it than I originally expected so I mark this as accepted, only I will actually use the one-liner solution given by Justin below because it is 2- lines.

Comment: @AttilaCsordas I didn't explain because I didn't know!  Josh's answer is informative.  While you're learning, I would also look into the `ggplot2` package.

Answer (score 4):

There may be a simpler way (I'm not terribly familiar with lattice) but:

```
library(lattice)
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(9), y = rnorm(9), z= letters[1:3])

xyplot(x~y,data=df,groups=z,
       par.settings=list(superpose.symbol=list(pch=1:3,
                                               col='black')))
```

Comment: it is working and it is a one-liner, thanks! The reasons I picked the other answer as accepted can be found in the comment there.

Comment: @AttilaCsordas -- Glad our answers helped. If you like them, you can also (in addition to accepting one of them) give them an upvote, by clicking the up-triangle to the left of the answer. (I only mention it because I'm guessing you'd want to know. You can also vote on any other questions and answers on the site.) Also, welcome to SO!

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution, based on `panel.superpose`, which you refer to in your question:

```
library(lattice)
xyplot(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length, groups = Species, data = iris,
panel = function(x,y,...){
    panel.superpose(x,y,..., pch=list("A","O","X"))
})
```

produces the following output:
[image: panel_superpose_example]

`lattice` uses **primary variables** (define the primary display), **conditioning variables** (define subgroups juxtaposed in different panels), and **grouping variables** (define subgroups superposed within panels).

The formula *Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length* and the grouping statement *groups = Species* specify the data to be plotted and pass it to `panel` which controls plotting. If groups != NULL `panel.superpose` passes the i-th element of the list assigned to `pch` to the i-th level of `groups`.

Using `...` for `panel` and `panel.superpose` one can avoid defining all function arguments and state only those which are to be customized.

`pars.settings` attaches custom settings to a specific object, unlike `lattice.options` which affects settings globally.